# Clinging to Dhamma!

Tags: theravada

Is it way of Arhat, who does not cling to dhamma? By non-clinging even to dhamma, he set free?
Dhammas are diad, 1) Samudaya Dhamma and 2) Nirodha Dhamma.

I feel lost I think due to these:
1)view clinging: such as eternalism (e.g., "The world and self are eternal")

2)self-doctrine clinging: self-identification with self-less entities.
Can only monks attain Nirvana? Have I to renounce for cessation of clinging?

Please guide us. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... you know the answers!

> (You said:) I have stumbled upon clinging to it, whenever I try to attach it, I
> feel more desire. It's like root of pain inside. When I try to detach,
> I feel more calmness.

Then clearly, an Arahant wouldn't get attached to dhamma.

I like to explain my experience this way:

Thinking something is better is **unskillful**. For example, "it's better to experience the taste of coffee than not experience any taste". "It's better to be a teacher". "It's better to know dhamma than not". "It's better to be an Arahant". **Similarly**, "it's better to not feel pain". "It's better to not be anxious". "It's better to not think". "It's better to not suffer".

> Can only monks attain Nirvana? Have I to renounce for cessation of clinging?

I don't think so, I think becoming an Arahant doesn't depend on any external conditions like whether you live in a temple, a forest, or a large building. I know that in Diamond Way Buddhism the lama is lay and it's considered fully enlightened. But you'll get a variety of answers to this questions, I suggest you to test it for yourself.

Comment: I agree completely as you said, sir. Lay people and homeless both can achieve it. What question most is purity of mind and detachment. The four truth already there. One have to search for it. Many lay disciples in India have attain the fruit, like Kabir, Nanak, Tukaram and Ravidas. Thank you, for your wise answer.

Comment: Kabir suggested that Truth is with the person who is on the path of righteousness, considered all creatures on earth as his own self, and who is passively detached from the affairs of the world.To know the Truth, suggested Kabir, drop the "I" or the ego.

Comment: He said, 'passively' not 'Actively' is the word here to underline.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it way of Arhat, who does not cling to dhamma? By non-clinging even to dhamma, he set free? Dhammas are diad, 1) Samudaya Dhamma and 2) Nirodha Dhamma.

The Dhamma is commonly referred to as a raft that gets one across the sea of Dukkha and reach the other shore of Nibbana. Now while the raft must be let go of once one's reached his destination, there's the obvious danger of letting go of it prematurely midstream: one will drown!

> Can only monks attain Nirvana? Have I to renounce for cessation of clinging?

No, not necessarily. While the monastic life apparently allows a much better more conducive environment to cultivate the Path, it ultimately depends on one's own effort and determination to get there, whether lay or monastic. There's no shortage of corrupted monks who hoard massive amount of wealth and break all the major precepts through relationship with many sexual partners, while there're lay folks who observe all the precepts and are way more advanced than their monastic counterparts in terms of spiritual progress.

Comment: Thank you sir, for answer. I agree totally. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Far off to touch the topic yet not even able to give up house and go for the holly life, good householder, or? As for the practice nothing is more needed as strong clinging to the Dhamma, starting with Sila/Vinaya (to possible even arive, get in touch with it). If it might come to a point where all except the Dhamma has given up, then one needs to drop this as well, or better has no more need to carry it on.

(One could, seldom, very seldom, come till Arahata-phala while living an householder life, but latest then it would get impossible and if not joining the Sangha of monks, not possible to go forth, one may not live longer then a week, which of course wouldn't not touch one)

`Have I to renounce for cessation of clinging?` **Yes**. That's the path and explicitly one factor of right resolve, wouldn't work otherwise, not even Jhana could be attained, yet not speak of paths and fruits or even final release from all tasks for this world.

Maybe a helpful talk: [The Essence of the Dhamma](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/beyond_en.html#ch8), good householder,and the Buddha didn't say that the path is an easy, burdenless (for desire for 'easy' going is the drive of defilements starting argue that letting go of the path would be the smart short-cut). Clinging strong to skillful, desire it, letting go of unskilful, not grasping after... this is right effort and when trouble arise, looking after it's real root, such as householding while after Arahatship.... useless and only painful as they are two ways and just one out.

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange, other world-binding but to bind on Dhamma toward release from ths wheel]*

Comment: Not satisfied with your answer sir. You hold clinging to dhamma. I have stumbled upon clinging to it, whenever I try to attach it, I feel more desire. It's like root of pain inside. When I try to detach, I feel more calmness. I am asking that.

Comment: This happens when your mind is washed away by stream of purity and one have insight. Then comes eyes of wisdom. Left and right eye of seeing, wisdom eyes. After that still there is root inside. I am asking that.

Comment: Maybe a helpful talk: [The Essence of the Dhamma](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/beyond_en.html#ch8), good householder,and the Buddha didn't say that the path is an easy, brudenless. Clinging strong to skillful, desire it, letting go of unskilful... this is right effort and when trouble arise, looking after it's real root, such as householding while after Arahatship.... useless and only painful as there are two ways and just one out.

Comment: Sir, your talk always bound with home and homelessness. When one asking the wisdom, better stay calm when one know it not. How many Arhat have you seen, who died within weeks after attaining Nirvana? Sheer mysticism. What is there to left when 'I' is already dropped? Even thought of renouncing is already renounced. Colouring those garments are for fool, while those who have wisdom,  need not one.

Comment: Why would a smart one raise a basic question? That's useless if just seeking to maintain ones personal views. May good householder find conducts toward the paths of liberation by himself with ease.